# Add flag counter in views Module(Search API index)

Tags: views, search, flags

I want to add flag counter of content in views field. Authenticated users can flag(bookmark) contents. I want to know how many users flaged a content, And I want to add this in views field(display the number of times a node is flagged by a certain flag by Users).

Notice; I'm using "Search API Index" in content part of views

How can I do it?

---

**UPDATE Question after using Vicky8888 method**;

I added below code in global php field of views

```
   <?php
   $flag = flag_get_flag('bookmarks');
   if ($flag) {
  print "Number of Flags:";
  print $flag->get_count($node->nid);
      }
    ?>
```

this code work in tpl.php file of content type, But It's showing "0" in views.
I got several errors in picture too.

[image]

after that I using JS code of Vicky8888.

```
Drupal.behaviors.your-theme = {

 attach: function (context, settings) { 

 //add your available class below
    jQuery('.view-id-top_users.view-display-id-page .views-field-php .flag-link-toggle').click(function(){

        jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
         location.reload();
        });
       });
      }
       };
```

I cleared "your-theme" and added "adaptivetheme", and cleared classes and added 
".view-content .views-field.views-field-php .field-content .flag-link-toggle".

after that I using this code in separate file and added

```
scripts[]=scripts/extracode.js
```

in adaptivetheme.info file.

I cleared cache and run cron too.
but It didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Use these two modules [drupal like](https://www.drupal.org/project/dlike) and [flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) simultaneously

Go to /admin/structure/flags create flag ,and  configure it properly.

Go to your view add  **Global: PHP field**

```
 <?php
print flag_create_link('bookmarks',$node->nid);

 $counts = flag_get_counts('node', $node->nid);
if(isset($counts['bookmarks'])){
 echo $counts['bookmarks'] .' Likes';
 }else{
      echo"no user flaged a content";
     }


 ?>
```

**And at last put this code in your themes js file**

```
Drupal.behaviors.your-theme = {

 attach: function (context, settings) { 

 //add your available class below
    jQuery('.view-id-top_users.view-display-id-page .views-field-php .flag-link-toggle').click(function(){

        jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
         location.reload();
        });
       });
      }
       };
```

**To add the flag link in your content type use code:**

```
   <?php
    global $user ,$base_url;
    if(!$user->uid) {
   $flag_link = flag_flag_link($flag, $action, $content_id);


   $flag_url = $flag_link['href'];
    if(isset($flag_link['query']['token'])) {

    $flag_url .= '?'.$flag_link['query']['token'];
}

?>

  <a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/user/login?destination=<?php echo      current_path();?>">MY-LINK</a>
```

Comment: unfortunately It's didn't work for me. but when I'm using below code, It's work but always shows "0" flag.   <?php
$flag = flag_get_flag('bookmarks');

if ($flag) {
  print "Number of flag";
  print $flag->get_count($node->nid);
}
?>   . This Code work when I using It in tpl.php file of content type but It didn't work in Views. I mean this code in tpl.php file shows number of flags but in views only shows "0".

Comment: i have the solution and i knows why its showing 0

Comment: Dear @vicky8888 I edited my question

Comment: use the exact code whatever i editted and then let me know,forget your code whatever you written for some time

Comment: if still it dont work then it may b issue of search api or it may be doing some mistake while configuring modules

Comment: I'm using your codes without any change. Exactly your codes. It doesn't work unfortunately. am I need to change Some values of your codes? please tell me about js code. how can i use it? where I should use it? Thank You.